# Spring REST Docs: how to replace request parameters

Tags: spring-restdocs

We want to replace request parameter.

In code, status is active. I use method maskStatus() to mask staus.

```
this.mockMvc
        .perform(RestDocumentationRequestBuilders.get("/helloworld")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .param("status", "active"))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andDo(document("{class-name}/{method-name}",
                Preprocessors.preprocessRequest(Preprocessors.prettyPrint(), Preprocessors.removeHeaders("Accept"),
                        maskStatus()),
                RequestDocumentation.requestParameters(RequestDocumentation.parameterWithName("status").description("The status"))

        ));
```

In the generated http-request.adoc, we want status to be "*status*":

```
[source,http,options="nowrap"]
----
GET /missioncontrol/v1/helloworld?status=*status* HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
----
```

But the actual result is :

```
[source,http,options="nowrap"]
----
GET /missioncontrol/v1/helloworld?status=active&status=*status* HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080

----
```

Code:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
public class TestControllerTest {

    @Rule
    public JUnitRestDocumentation restDocumentation = new JUnitRestDocumentation( "target/snippets");

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    @Autowired
    private FilterChainProxy springSecurityFilterChain;

    protected MockMvc mockMvc;


    @Before
    public void setup() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac)
                .apply(MockMvcRestDocumentation.documentationConfiguration(this.restDocumentation))     
                .addFilter(springSecurityFilterChain)
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void hellWorldTest() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc
        .perform(RestDocumentationRequestBuilders.get("/helloworld")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .param("status", "active"))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andDo(document("{class-name}/{method-name}",
                Preprocessors.preprocessRequest(Preprocessors.prettyPrint(), Preprocessors.removeHeaders("Accept"),
                        maskStatus()),
                RequestDocumentation.requestParameters(RequestDocumentation.parameterWithName("status").description("The status"))

        ));
    }

    private OperationPreprocessor maskStatus() {
        return new StatusMaskingPreprocessor();
    }

    private static class StatusMaskingPreprocessor implements OperationPreprocessor {

        @Override
        public OperationRequest preprocess(OperationRequest request) {
            Parameters parameters = new Parameters();
            parameters.set("status", "*status*");
            return new OperationRequestFactory().create(request.getUri(),
                    request.getMethod(), request.getContent(), request.getHeaders(),
                    parameters, request.getParts());
        }

        @Override
        public OperationResponse preprocess(OperationResponse response) {
            return response;
        }

    }
```

Questions:
**We want to replace the status. But it does not work and it just appends the new assignment. Why?**

Other ways I tried:

```
@Test
    public void hellWorldTest() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc
        .perform(RestDocumentationRequestBuilders.get("/helloworld")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .param("status", "active"))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andDo(document("{class-name}/{method-name}",
                Preprocessors.preprocessRequest(Preprocessors.prettyPrint(), Preprocessors.removeHeaders("Accept"),
                        Preprocessors.modifyParameters().remove("status").set("status", "*status*")),
                RequestDocumentation.requestParameters(RequestDocumentation.parameterWithName("status").description("The status"))

        ));
    }
```

The result is still  "GET /helloworld?status=active&status=*status* HTTP/1.1"

Anybody knows how to replace request parameters?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are making a `GET` request and, therefore, the `status` will be part of the query string of the request's URI. The problem is that the preprocessors (both your custom implementation and REST Docs' built-in one) are modifying the parameters but are not making a corresponding change to the URI. You could fix the problem by updating `StatusMaskingPreprocessor` to modify the URI as well as the parameters.

I've opened a [Spring REST Docs issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-restdocs/issues/682) to see if we can fix this in a general purpose manner.